# How to reduce query execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have millions of records in my MasterTable with different CustNo and I want to reduce the query execution time. Is there a more efficient query for this?

```
SELECT a.CustNo AS CustNo ,
       CAST(a.CustRating as decimal(10,9) AS CustRating,
       a.RatingDate AS RatingDate,
       CAST((a.CustRating-b.CustRating) as decimal(10,9)) AS [Rating Difference]
FROM MasterTable a
JOIN MasterTable b
ON b.CustNo = a.CustNo
ORDER BY CustNo
```

This is the original table [MasterTable]

```
CustNo  CustRating  RatingDate
101AAA  0.000500000 "2016-01-08 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000750 "2016-01-12 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000550 "2016-01-22 00:00:00.000"
101AAA  0.000000000 "2016-01-27 00:00:00.000"
```

The objective here is to calculate the difference in customer rating in every row based on customer no. Is there a more efficient way to do this? For instance, if the custNo is the same, I want to get the difference in rating for the current record and the previous record.

Comment: Why are you doin a `SELF JOIN`?

Comment: What is your query supposed to do? What indexes are on the table? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @FelixPamittan I have amended the question - hope it helps to understand better what I wanted.

Comment: Without execution I see that [`Rating Difference]` is always 0 (probably, sometimes null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`LAG`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function instead:

> Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join in SQL Server 2016. LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset that comes before the current row. Use this analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the current row with values in a previous row

```
SELECT
    CustNo AS CustNo,
    CAST(CustRating AS DECIMAL(10, 9)) AS CustRating,
    RatingDate AS RatingDate,
    CAST((CustRating - LAG(CustRating, 1, 0) OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY RatingDate)) AS DECIMAL(10, 9)) AS [Rating Difference]
FROM MasterTable
ORDER BY CustNo, RatingDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to be considered an answer.

Just a minor tweak to Felix.   In his lag, he had the default set to 0.   So in the first observation the rating difference is +.0005.   IMHO, a new rating is not a change (It is a factor in Rate-Volume-Variance Reporting)

The only change I made to Felix's query was >>>LAG(CustRating, 1, CustRating)<<<

```
Declare @MasterTable table (CustNo varchar(50),CustRating decimal(11,9),RatingDate Date)
Insert Into @MasterTable (CustNo,CustRating,RatingDate) values 
('101AAA',  0.000500000,'2016-01-08'),
('101AAA',  0.000000750,'2016-01-12'),
('101AAA',  0.000000550,'2016-01-22'),
('101AAA',  0.000000000,'2016-01-27')

    SELECT
        CustNo AS CustNo,
        CAST(CustRating AS DECIMAL(10, 9)) AS CustRating,
        RatingDate AS RatingDate,
        CAST((CustRating - LAG(CustRating, 1, CustRating) OVER(PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY RatingDate)) AS DECIMAL(10, 9)) AS [Rating Difference]
    FROM @MasterTable
    ORDER BY CustNo, RatingDate
```

The Results

```
CustNo  CustRating  RatingDate  Rating Difference
101AAA  0.000500000 2016-01-08  0.000000000
101AAA  0.000000750 2016-01-12  -0.000499250
101AAA  0.000000550 2016-01-22  -0.000000200
101AAA  0.000000000 2016-01-27  -0.000000550
```